# Basic exercise on localization of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $A$ be a ring and $\mathfrak m\subset A$ be a maximal ideal. Show that the canonical map $A\to A_\mathfrak m$ induces an isomorphism $A/\mathfrak m^r\cong A_\mathfrak m/(\mathfrak mA_\mathfrak m)^r$, for any positive integer $r$.

I think that this exercise could be done writing a suitable exact sequence, and then using that the localization is an exact functor. The problem is finding the sequence: I thought to start from $\mathfrak m \to A\to A/\mathfrak m$ or $A\to A_\mathfrak m\to A_\mathfrak m/A$ but I don't see how I could modify one of them to insert the $r$. Can you only give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the key insight is that for $S=A\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ we have that $S^{-1}(A/\mathfrak{m}^n)=A/\mathfrak{m}^n$.

Comment: Thank you, I also didn't realize that $\mathfrak m^rA_\mathfrak m\cong (\mathfrak m A _\mathfrak m)^r$.